# OpenWRT - how to convert failsafe mode to normal boot?

Tags: linux, networking, home-networking, openwrt

I know that sounds strange. Here's some background: [OpenWRT - how to do initial login (ssh) if 192.168.1.1 can't be routed?](https://superuser.com/q/1099930/607172)

Essentially, I flashed openWRT and the normal boot mode is broken. I have a working configuration in failsafe mode, as well as a lot of additional configuration that I've done. For whatever reason, when I'm in failsafe mode, my changes persist. If I reboot, it boots the normal mode, which fails and hangs. Status light never changes, Ethernet ports never get power (judging by their LEDs), nothing occurs over the ports, no ping, no ssh etc. I have to cut power 3-5 times every time I reboot, until it reboots back to failsafe, with all my changes that I've made still there. It's very strange.

Question: Is there an easy way to copy failsafe to main boot mode, or should I back it up and reflash? If I restore a backup that was made while in failsafe, does that backup contain data from failsafe or normal mode? I am talking about the config backup done thru Luci, not a filesystem backup.

Answer (score 0):

According to this explanation:
https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/generic.failsafe
You really should not be able to save any configuration in FailSafe mode since "...failsafe mode bypasses all configuration located on the JFFS2 partition (the writable 'overlay' filesystem), and instead uses a basic set of hard coded defaults located on the SquashFS partition (that is the read-only partition containing the router OS). "
I strongly recommend that you reflash, but before that take a look once more what OpenWRT team recommends about your router:
https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/start

Comment: This was my initial thought too. However, whenever I reboot I have to cut power several times until it reboots into the working configuration. The device itself also has its own failsafe partitioning scheme in the firmware: there are two partitions, one normal and one recovery. When flashing, the image gets written to recovery, and then if the flash is successful, the firmware switches the two partitions (recovery becomes the normal partition, vice versa). Then if there are 3 failed boots in a row, it switches the partitions again, preventing the device from being bricked by a failed flash.

Comment: But I would expect that if I'm forcing a recovery that it would stick and I wouldn't have to do it every time I reboot. I guess a reflash is called for.